# Submitting GA UTM Variables to Pardot via Form Handler

Tags: google-analytics, pardot

Has anyone ever managed to get GA UTM tracking variables into Pardot via the API? If you use the iframe, then all of the GA variables are picked up automatically, but when you submit directly via a form handler, the information doesn't get set (presumably because it can't read the cookies).

Pardot support seem to think this can be done via the API by assigning visitors and prospects, but the documentation appears to be skimpy/non-existent. Has anyone ever had to do this and could point me in the right direction of where I should be looking in the docs or the API?

Comment: "presumably because it can't read the cookies" - current versions of GA do not store utm parameters in the cookies, instead campaign information is computed on the GA servers based on the incoming referer to the landing page. Don't know Pardot, but probably sending submitting data "directly" does not connect to the running GA session and the campaign information is lost.